# Error: Request is too large when Uploading Youtube Video via API

Tags: post, youtube, axios, youtube-api

I'm getting an error when trying to upload a Youtube video (3MB only) via a POST request saying that the request is too large. What am I missing?

```js
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'video/*',
        'Authorization': `Bearer <my_access_token>`
    },
    params: {
        'uploadType': 'resumable',
        'key': <my_api_key>,
        'part': 'snippet,status',
        'snippet': {
            'title': 'Test Upload 1',
            'description': 'Test Description 1',
            'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2'],
            'defaultLanguage': "en_US",
            'categoryId': '24'
        },
        'status': {
            'privacyStatus': "private"
        },
    },
    data: fs.createReadStream(`${process.cwd()}/video.mp4`),
})
.then( res => console.log(res))
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you get, also it would be great if you could link the api reference for the API you are using, there seems to be an alternative youtube API which allows uploading videos to a different endpoint to the one in your code snippet. You can see the details here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: @dc3726 At the moment, I'm not getting any responses at all. I clicked on the URL you provided thanks and it seems like the URL is correct. The other URL on that page is for the scope only.

Comment: @dc3726 I posted the Error log in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252689/error-status-400-when-uploading-to-youtube-api-v3

Comment: Hi I am getting same issue, please post solution if you found any